# chicken scheme ; error while using let inside a function

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

what is wrong with this code ?

```
(define (make-node key data )
        (list key data 'null 'null ) )

(define (right)(2) )
(define (left) (3) )          
;;inserts a key to the tree
;; string x string ->  list 
(define (insert lst key data )
          (if (null? lst )
               (make-node key data )
               (cond ( [(string>? key (car lst))  (list-set lst 2 (insert lst key data))  ]
                       [(string<? key (car lst))  (list-set lst 3 (insert lst key data))   ]
                       [(string=? key (car lst))  (list-set lst 1 data )   ]
                      ))))

 (define (list-set lst ix data )   
          (if (eqv? ix 0 ) ( cons data (cdr lst )  ) ( cons (car lst)  (list-set ( cdr lst) ( - ix 1 )  data ))))         


( define (newdiction) [   
                        let ( ( [ tree '() ]) [ (msg  key data  )[ cond ( (eqv? msg 'insert ) [ set! tree (insert tree key data )    ]   ) ] ] )
                         ] )
```

the chicken scheme interpreter spits:

```
CHICKEN
(c) 2008-2014, The Chicken Team
(c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
Version 4.9.0.1 (stability/4.9.0) (rev 8b3189b)
linux-unix-gnu-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
bootstrapped 2014-06-07
; loading dict.scm ...
Error: during expansion of (let ...) - in `let' - symbol expected: (let (((tree (quote ()))) ((msg key data) (cond ((eqv? msg (quote insert)) (set! tree (insert tree key data)))))))
    Call history:
    <syntax>      (define (list-set lst ix data) (if (eqv? ix 0) (cons data (cdr lst)) (cons (car lst) (list-set (cdr lst...
    <syntax>      (##core#set! list-set (##core#lambda (lst ix data) (if (eqv? ix 0) (cons data (cdr lst)) (cons (car lst...
    <syntax>      (##core#lambda (lst ix data) (if (eqv? ix 0) (cons data (cdr lst)) (cons (car lst) (list-set (cdr lst...
    <syntax>      [list-set] (##core#begin (##core#if (eqv? ix 0) (cons data (cdr lst)) (cons (car lst) (list-set (cdr lst) (- ix...
    <syntax>      [list-set] (##core#if (eqv? ix 0) (cons data (cdr lst)) (cons (car lst) (list-set (cdr lst) (- ix 1) data)))
    <syntax>      [list-set] (eqv? ix 0)
    <syntax>      [list-set] (cons data (cdr lst))
    <syntax>      [list-set] (cdr lst)
    <syntax>      [list-set] (cons (car lst) (list-set (cdr lst) (- ix 1) data))
    <syntax>      [list-set] (car lst)
    <syntax>      [list-set] (list-set (cdr lst) (- ix 1) data)
    <syntax>      [list-set] (cdr lst)
    <syntax>      [list-set] (- ix 1)
    <syntax>      (define (newdiction) (let (((tree (quote ()))) ((msg key data) (cond ((eqv? msg (quote insert)) (set......
    <syntax>      (##core#set! newdiction (##core#lambda () (let (((tree (quote ()))) ((msg key data) (cond ((eqv? msg...
    <syntax>      (##core#lambda () (let (((tree (quote ()))) ((msg key data) (cond ((eqv? msg (quote insert)) (set! t......    <--
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is  suffering from too many parentheses. So Scheme is very flexible and thus you can have code like this:

```
((som-func som-arg) some-other-arg)
```

What is happening there? Well. Since `(some-func som-arg)` is not a special form or macro it has to be an expression that leads to a function so it gets evaluated. Since `some-func` is not a special form or macro it has to be an expression that leads to a function and thus it evalautes it and `some-arg` and applies it. The result will be the function to call with the evaluation of `some-other-arg` as the argument.

I see you use `[ ... ]` as well as `( ... )`. Know that the difference between these are just how they look and the interpretation of them is the same. Thus if you change `(+ 1 2)` to `[+ 1 2]` you get `3` both times. No difference. You may use them to indicate some sort of grouping in macros like `let`, but it makes no difference for the implementation.

If you look at your `let`:

```
(let ([(tree '())] ...)
  body ...)
```

So the first variable is `(tree '())` with **no value**.. But `(tree '())` isn't a symbol but a list.

```
(let ([tree '()] ...)
  body ...)
```

Here `tree` is bound to `'()`. see?
Now looking at you first `cond` you have **one** term. Usually `cond` has more than two or else a simple `if` would suffice. The predicate in the one term is:

```
[(string>? key (car lst)) (list-set lst 2 (insert lst key data))]
```

Now without the extra `( ... )` around the whole thing the whole code above would become a term instead of just playing a predicate.

But hang on.. Why do you have `cond` **and** `if`. A `cond` is a `if-elseif-else`. Isn't there a way to make the whole thing one `cond`? Yes! This is the same with one `cond`:

```
(define (insert lst key data)
  (cond
    [(null? lst) (make-node key data)]
    [(string>? key (car lst)) (list-set lst 2 (insert lst key data))]
    [(string<? key (car lst)) (list-set lst 3 (insert lst key data))]
    [else (list-set lst 1 data)]))
```

I noticed also that you check if it's less than, greater than and equal to, but no `else` (alternative) so I assumed if it weren't less or greater than that it must be equal and thus everything goes in the last term since you now have a complete venn diagram.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `(let (((tree '()) ...)` but `let` expects a list of variable/value pairs. So you'd have to remove one set of parentheses: `(let ((tree '())) ...)`

In Lisp and Scheme, parentheses have a very specific meaning, you can't just add an extra set of parentheses around an expression without changing its meaning, like you can in many languages.